# Nameserver changes and Tumblr custom URL's

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy, nameserver, cname, tumblr

I'm hoping I can get some help on some trouble I'm having with using a custom url for my tumblr blog.

To begin with I'll give a background to my setup for my site -
I'm using GoDaddy for as my domain name host and Dreamhost for my web hosting
I'm intending to make a WordPress based website on the main domain, with the addition of Tumblr on a sub domains
I intend to add further non WordPress based pages on other sub domains of the main URL in the future

My Tumblr blog used to point to the custom URL, but recently I changed the name servers on GoDaddy to point towards Dreamhost's servers (ns1, ns2, ns3), as I wan4t to host a web page on the main URL as well as set up an email address for myself via Dreamhost.

On my GoDaddy profile, my CNAME & A (Host) @ are both pointing to Tumblr - domains.Tumblr.com and 66.6.44.4 respectively, where domains is a placeholder for my Tumblr blog name - there also seems to be a www host for CNAME on Godaddy.

To summarize -

> A (Host) > @ = 66.6.44.4
>
> CNAME (Alias) > blog = [name].tumblr.com
>
> CNAME (Alias) > @ = [empty]

My current issues are as follows -

1 - My Tumblr page wont load on the sub domain address though the favicon still appears, how can I get my blog up and running on the sub domain address again?

2 - When I try to add a hosting/sub domain on Dreamhost an error message occurs telling me that "You can't add that domain: you don't have permission to add", what is this caused by and how do I resolve it?

3. Do I need to add something to the @ host for the CNAME? Should I have both CNAME and A name @ host point towards tumblr or only one?

Comment: Do you have to connect it at Tumblr?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find my answer, basically after asking my hosting help it turned out the issue was my hosting account being old so not configured quite right, meaning the general instructions on tumblr for custom urls was correct.